# Textarea text overflow

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea

I have written a forum, but I've got one problem... The text from the posts overflows, it just passes the div even though it has a set width. It never creates a linebreak. I've have tried replacing \r\n with 
, but with no success. If it would have been pure HTML it wouldn't react like this. The text is of course generated from a textarea which is saved in a database and then retrieved.

Is there any way of solving this issue of mine?

Thanks for your time!

ZyteX

Comment: Some sample of the offending output would be more helpful than just a verbal description.

Comment: Some sample of.... well, anything really... would be helpful.

Comment: You've taken the time to respond to answers, but not to update your question. Add some samples if you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to answer this anymore! I solved it by making a system where you need to have atleast two words and where the length of the words can not be longer than 40 char.

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

Pure guess, since no jsfiddle setup:

Your text is displayed in a zone that has a style `white-space: nowrap;` OR the text has no space in it, so it cannot be splitted on multiple lines.

Try setting `white-space: normal;` explicitely.

Comment: My text which I putted in doesn't have any spaces in it, but is there any way of creating multiple lines anyway?

Comment: If you don't have any line breaking character (such as spaces), then you would have to create jscript to break your lines every X character...

Answer (score 0):

Try to set max-width on div. That should force that div cannot overflow its width.